# intelij always returns 404 for find jar on web

Tags: intellij-idea

I always get an 404 error in intelij ide when I try to "find jar on web". The following appears:

[image]

And I can't find a way to change the urls intelij is using. I don't use a proxy.

How to configure this to make it work?

Comment: Perhaps the URL is broken. Have you tried this to specify download location: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/downloading-libraries-from-maven-repositories.html?origin=old_help

Comment: That works, yes! @Bajal

Comment: Cool, I added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/downloading-libraries-from-maven-repositories.html?origin=old_help), you may open the *Project structure* (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> on mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on windows). Go to Libraries pane on the left and click on the + button and choose "From Maven..."

Provide the correct Maven URL for the jar that you need in the resulting dialog.

Screenshot from Intellij 15.0.1:

[image]